# Flutter Semaphore timeout

Tags: flutter, arduino, arduino-uno

I'm trying to use Flutter to make an app that communicates with an Arduino via wifi but I'm getting an error as such: `Error sending request: The semaphore timeout period has expired`

I had code yesterday where if you pushed a button on the Flutter app it worked to make the Arduino LED light up. Which I got working. Today I took it a step up by trying to send data from the text box and print it in the serial of the Arduino which is connected to my other computer

The code below is my flutter code

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Arduino Communication'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: ArduinoCommunicationWidget(
              key: UniqueKey()), // Assign a UniqueKey
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ArduinoCommunicationWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const ArduinoCommunicationWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ArduinoCommunicationWidgetState createState() =>
      _ArduinoCommunicationWidgetState();
}

class _ArduinoCommunicationWidgetState
    extends State<ArduinoCommunicationWidget> {
  TextEditingController textController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        TextField(
          controller: textController,
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
            hintText: 'Enter text to send to Arduino',
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 10),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            // Send the text to Arduino
            _sendRequest(textController.text);
          },
          child: const Text('Send Text to Arduino'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Future<void> _sendRequest(String text) async {
    final Uri uri = Uri.parse(
        'http://192.168.129.208/data'); // Change the URI path accordingly

    try {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print('test1');
      }
      final response = await http.post(
        uri,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'},
        body: text,
      );
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        if (kDebugMode) {
          print('Text sent successfully: $text');
        }
      } else {
        if (kDebugMode) {
          print('Failed to send text. Status code: ${response.statusCode}');
          print('Response body: ${response.body}');
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print('Error sending request: $e');
      }
   
 }
}
```

This is my arduino code. i also changed the SSID and pass varaibles to filler variables in order not to dox myself.
Also my board is the Arduino Uno WiFi Rev2

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <WiFiNINA.h>

char ssid[] = "Your_wifi_SSUD"; 
char pass[] = "Your_wifi_Password"; 
int Led = LED_BUILTIN;  // Built-in LED pin
bool isConnected = false; // Flag to track Wi-Fi connection status

WiFiServer server(80);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // Check for the presence of the WiFiNINA module
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_MODULE) {
    Serial.println("Communication with WiFi module failed!");
    while (true);
  }

  // Attempt to connect to Wi-Fi
  while (WiFi.begin(ssid, pass) != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print("Attempting to connect to SSID: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    delay(1000);
  }

  isConnected = true; // Set connection status flag
  digitalWrite(Led, HIGH); // Turn on the built-in LED

  Serial.println("WiFi connected");

  // Start the server
  server.begin();
}

void loop() {
  // Print WiFi connection status
  if (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED && isConnected) {
    isConnected = false;
    digitalWrite(Led, LOW); // Turn off the built-in LED
    Serial.println("WiFi connection lost");
  } else if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED && !isConnected) {
    isConnected = true;
    digitalWrite(Led, HIGH); // Turn on the built-in LED
    Serial.println("WiFi reconnected");
  }

  WiFiClient client = server.available();

  if (client) {
    Serial.println("New client connected");

    // Read the request
    String request = client.readStringUntil('\r');
    client.flush();

    // Print the received text from Flutter to the serial monitor
    Serial.print("Received from Flutter: ");
    Serial.println(request);

    client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
    client.println("Content-Type: text/plain");
    client.println();
    client.println("Data received successfully");
    client.stop();

    Serial.println("Client disconnected");
  }

  delay(1000);
}
```

When I had this working yesterday with the button the flutter code would default to printing "error sending request" even though the request failed. I believe the error is when I say

```
await http.post
```

But I don't know how to fix it.

Also to be more clear. Even though the flutter says "error sending request" the Arduino did receive a request.